# My eyes won't stay in the socket

Tags: bones

Every time I parent my eyes to my bones, (I have two meshes for the eyes, but this was happening even when it was just one mesh) they won't rotate in place. The one on the left stays in the eye and won't move around but the one on the right is moving into the eyelid.
This is the stagnant one.

[image]

This happens to the right eye when I move the middle bone that controls them both. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Oops. Here, [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Jr4dyvKM" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Jr4dyvKM/) I forgot to ad it to my post, lol.

Comment: what do you mean by "moving into the eyelid" and "stagnant"? Your meshes and bones are not symmetrical and even in rest pose the eye mesh goes out of the eyelid mesh, I'm not sure you're talking about that but maybe you should fix the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that they're not symmetrical, will have to fix that. I messed up on the wording when using stagnant, and should have said the first image was the eyes without a pose, but when I move them around with the middle bone that controls where the eyes should look, the eye on the right rolls into the eyelid while the one on the left rolls in place like an eye should. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: when you mean right and left eyes, do you mean his right and left or the eye on the right and the eye on the left? For me, his right eye doesn't roll properly but I guess you need to make sure everything is well aligned and centered, no?

Comment: I meant the left and right of the armature, not my left and right, sorry for the confusion. I was trying to align the armature so it's in the same place in pose mode and edit mode but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Have any idea why it's not rolling like it should?

Comment: first why don't you join all your meshes into one object, then parent With Empty Groups, then assign each mesh the group it is supposed to be part of. Also make sure that everything is well aligned. There's no reason it would not work

Comment: I tried it just now, and the eyes aren't moving at all now. (I'll probably keep all the objects as one mesh though, so thanks for that tip)

Comment: Yes you need to reassign each mesh to the good vertex group  ;)

Comment: I did, that's how I got the result that I have now.

Comment: So maybe share the latest version  ;)

Comment: Here it is. Thanks for the continuous help. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=wMKZDbEN" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/wMKZDbEN/)

Comment: You need to reactivate the bones Deform option for Eyeball.R and Eyeball.L ;)

Comment: Did that, eyes are moving now, but still rolling outside the lids.

Comment: Maybe it will be faster to redo the eyes and target bones: Delete these bones, create a sphere that has the same size as one of your eye, put it at the same place, use shift S to put the 3D cursor at its center, create a new bone at the exact same place, rotate it with the 3D cursor as pivot, same thing for the other eye, duplicate them to create the targets, etc...

Comment: Probably. I keep getting this issue though, so I was hoping to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: yes because you need to be extra-precise, you need to put the head of the bone at the exact center, you need your eyelid sphere to be exactly parallel to the eye sphere, etc... maybe scale up a bit the eyelid for example. And anyway you had some issues here with Deform not enabled, eye bone and target not aligned, eye bone and eye mesh not aligned, etc...

Comment: Okay. I'll try it out. Thanks for the help, hopefully, this process gets easier as I get better at rigging, lol.